# can't create folder with expect script

Tags: shell, sftp, expect

I have this script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set DATE [exec date +%F]
spawn sftp user@192.168.0.20
expect "password:"
send "password\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /getfile/$DATE/ \n"
expect "sftp>"
send "lcd /putfile/ \n"
expect "sftp>"
send "mkdir $DATE"
expect "sftp>"
send "lcd /putfile/$DATE \n"
expect "sftp>"
send "mget *.* \n"
expect "sftp>"

send "quit \n"
```

everything works here, but it does not create the directory. The error is:

> cant create directory

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you use these commands directly in shell and what's the response of `mkdir`?

Comment: I can use mkdir in shell and it create directory without any issue, and also when I use expect Shell alone it can create directory but not in above script!!! @sputnick  need this script to run in cron so generating key I have not done if you have any example would appreciate if

Comment: i'm trying to create directory in destination BTW...maybe in this script I try to create in getfile location?? not sure

Comment: @hi4ppl :Your script will try to create in the directory in the remote machine. Use `lmkdir` to create directory in the local machine.

Comment: Not really a problem, but why do you send spaces before the return? Why do you end the directory name with a slash? If I remember correctly, expect's `send` command usually uses `\r` (not `\n`) as the RETURN character.

Comment: There's no *"cant create directory"* error message in `sftp`. There's "Couldn't create directory", followed by error details. It would help, if you share with as a real and exact error you are getting.

Comment: Don't need to call out to `date`: expect has built-in datetime handling: `set DATE [timestamp -format %Y-%m-%d]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to download files to a **local** new directory, why not create this directory with expect's exec instead of with sftp?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set DATE [exec date +%F]
exec mkdir "$DATE"
cd "$DATE"
spawn ...
```